# AES Crypto C# compatible Java

Tags: java, c#, passwords, aes

I have this code in C # which generates an encrypted password.
I would like to make it compatible in Java.

Code C#

```
private static string ccs = "&Ux#B*******";

    private static ICryptoTransform __Get_AES128_Transform(string password, bool AsDecryptor)
    {
        const int KEY_SIZE = 16;
        var sha256CryptoServiceProvider = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        var hash = sha256CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password));
        var key = new byte[KEY_SIZE];
        var iv = new byte[KEY_SIZE];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(hash, 0, key, 0, KEY_SIZE);
        if (AsDecryptor)
            return new AesCryptoServiceProvider().CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
        else
            return new AesCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
    }

    public static string Encrypt(this string Value)
    {
        byte[] Buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Value);
        using (ICryptoTransform transform = __Get_AES128_Transform(ccs, false))
        {
            byte[] encyptedBlob = transform.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encyptedBlob);
        }
    }
```

Could anyone give a direction to decrypt in java?

Comment: do you need that code specifically?

Comment: yes, unfortunately this code is already running.  ;/  because?

Comment: Well, `Unicode` is basically a badly named UTF-16LE, other than that: what have you tried? SO is not a code translation service.

Answer (score 0):

My answer interoperable encrypt, I hope this helps you. Result can be decrypted from any platform - C# code or Android/Java code.

- Encrypt from C# -> Decrypt from C#, Android, Java.
- Encrypt from Android -> Decrypt from Android, Java, C#.
- Encrypt from Java -> Decrypt from Java, Android, C#.
- The result of encrypt contains the encrypted text + IV.
- IV is generated using secure random algoritm.

**Encrypt process**

1. Transform plaintext => plaintextBytes
2. Transform password => passwordBytes => Sha256(passwordbytes) = passwordHashBytes
3. generate random IV bytes = ivBytes
4. encrypt using plaintextbytes and passwordHashBytes
5. join (encryptedbytes + ivBytes)
6. Transform to base64 joined bytes.

**Decrypt process**

1. Transform base64 string to bytes.
2. Split array encryptedBytes, ivBytes
3. Transform password => passwordBytes => Sha256(passwordbytes) = passwordHashBytes
4. Decrypt using ivBytes, EncryptedBytes, PasswordHashBytes
5. Transform DecryptedBytes to String

The IV is randomized in every Encrypt process to get different output with same text and avoid to intruders/attackers get original text easily.

The default mode is CBC.

The encoding used is UTF-8. UTF-8 is the most widely used encoding on the web. Check [Usage of character encodings broken down by ranking](https://w3techs.com/technologies/cross/character_encoding/ranking)

---

**References**

[Initialization vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)
[Block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)

---

> **C# Implementation**

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public enum HashAlgorithm
{
    MD5,
    SHA1,
    SHA256,
    SHA384,
    SHA512
}

public class HashManager
{
    public static byte[] ToRawHash(byte[] data, HashAlgorithm algorithm)
    {
        byte[] hash;
        switch (algorithm)
        {
            case HashAlgorithm.MD5:
                MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
                hash = md5.ComputeHash(data, 0, data.Length);
                return hash;
            case HashAlgorithm.SHA1:
                SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
                hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);
                return hash;
            case HashAlgorithm.SHA256:
                SHA256Managed sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
                hash = sha256.ComputeHash(data);
                return hash;
            case HashAlgorithm.SHA384:
                SHA384Managed sha384 = new SHA384Managed();
                hash = sha384.ComputeHash(data);
                return hash;
            case HashAlgorithm.SHA512:
                SHA512Managed sha512 = new SHA512Managed();
                hash = sha512.ComputeHash(data, 0, data.Length);
                return hash;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Algorithm");
        }
    }
}

public class AesManager
{
    private const int MAX_IV_LENGTH = 16;
    private const int MAX_KEY_LENGTH = 32;

    private static byte[] GenerateValidKey(byte[] keyBytes)
    {
        byte[] ret = new byte[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
        byte[] hash = HashManager.ToRawHash(keyBytes, HashAlgorithm.SHA256);
        Array.Copy(hash, ret, MAX_KEY_LENGTH);
        return ret;
    }


    public static byte[] EncryptRaw(byte[] PlainBytes, byte[] Key)
    {
        AesManaged AesAlgorithm = new AesManaged()
        {
            Key = GenerateValidKey(Key)
        };
        AesAlgorithm.GenerateIV();
        var Encrypted = AesAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(PlainBytes, 0, PlainBytes.Length);
        byte[] ret = new byte[Encrypted.Length + MAX_IV_LENGTH];
        Array.Copy(Encrypted, ret, Encrypted.Length);
        Array.Copy(AesAlgorithm.IV, 0, ret, ret.Length - MAX_IV_LENGTH, MAX_IV_LENGTH);
        return ret;
    }

    public static byte[] DecryptRaw(byte[] CipherBytes, byte[] Key)
    {
        AesManaged AesAlgorithm = new AesManaged()
        {
            Key = GenerateValidKey(Key)
        };
        byte[] IV = new byte[MAX_IV_LENGTH];
        Array.Copy(CipherBytes, CipherBytes.Length - MAX_IV_LENGTH, IV, 0, MAX_IV_LENGTH);
        AesAlgorithm.IV = IV;
        byte[] RealBytes = new byte[CipherBytes.Length - MAX_IV_LENGTH];
        Array.Copy(CipherBytes, RealBytes, CipherBytes.Length - MAX_IV_LENGTH);
        return AesAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(RealBytes, 0, RealBytes.Length); ;
    }


    public static String EncryptToBase64(String Plaintext, String Key)
    {
        byte[] PlainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Plaintext);
        return Base64Manager.ToBase64(EncryptRaw(PlainBytes, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key)), false);
    }



    public static String DecryptFromBase64(String CipherText, String Key)
    {
        byte[] CiPherBytes = Base64Manager.Base64ToByteArray(CipherText);
        byte[] Encrypted = DecryptRaw(CiPherBytes, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key));
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encrypted, 0, Encrypted.Length);
    }

}

public class Base64Manager
{
    public static byte[] Base64ToByteArray(String base64)
    {
        return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    }

    public static String ToBase64(byte[] data, Boolean insertLineBreaks = default(Boolean))
    {
        return insertLineBreaks ? Convert.ToBase64String(data, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks) : Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string plainText = "plain text";
        string password = "password";
        string encrypted = AesManager.EncryptToBase64(plainText, password);
        Console.WriteLine(encrypted);
        Console.WriteLine(AesManager.DecryptFromBase64(encrypted, password));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

> **Android/Java Implementation**

```
public enum HashAlgorithm {

    SHA512("SHA-512"),
    SHA256("SHA-256"),
    SHA384("SHA-384"),
    SHA1("SHA-1"),
    MD5("MD5");

    private String Value = "";

    HashAlgorithm(String Value) {
        this.Value = Value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Value;
    }

}
```

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
public class HashManager {
    public static byte[] toRawHash(byte[] data,
                                   HashAlgorithm algorithm) throws Exception
    {
        byte[] buffer = data;
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm.toString());
        messageDigest.reset();
        messageDigest.update(buffer);
        return messageDigest.digest();
    }
}
```

*Base64Manager class Android implementation*

```
    import android.util.Base64;
    
    public class Base64Manager {
        public static String toBase64(byte[] data,
                                      boolean insertLineBreaks) throws Exception
        {
            String ret;
            if (insertLineBreaks)
            {
                ret = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
            }
            else
            {
                ret = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    
        public static String toBase64(String data,
                                      boolean insertLineBreaks) throws Exception
        {
            return toBase64(data.getBytes("UTF-8"), insertLineBreaks);
        }
    
        public static byte[] base64ToByteArray(String base64) throws Exception
        {
            return base64.contains(System.getProperty("line.separator")) ? Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT) : Base64.decode(base64, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        }
    }
```

*Base64Manager class Java8+ implementation*

```
    import java.util.Base64;
    
    public class Base64Manager {    
        public static String toBase64(byte[] data, Boolean insertLineBreaks) throws Exception {
            String ret;
            if (insertLineBreaks) {
                ret = Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(data);
            } else {
                ret = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    
        public static String toBase64(String data, Boolean insertLineBreaks) throws Exception {
            return toBase64(data.getBytes("UTF-8" ), insertLineBreaks);
        }
    
        public static byte[] base64ToByteArray(String base64) throws Exception {
            return base64.contains(System.getProperty("line.separator")) ? Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(base64) : Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64);
        }    
    }
```

```
    import java.security.SecureRandom;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
    
    public class AesManager {
    
        private static final int MAX_IV_LENGTH = 16;
        private static final int MAX_KEY_LENGTH = 32;
    
        public static String decryptFromBase64(String cipherText, String key) throws Exception {
            byte[] CiPherBytes = Base64Manager.base64ToByteArray(cipherText);
            byte[] KeyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
            return new String((decryptRaw(CiPherBytes, KeyBytes)));
        }
    
        public static byte[] generateValidKey(byte[] key) throws Exception {
            return Arrays.copyOf(HashManager.toRawHash(key, HashAlgorithm.SHA256), MAX_KEY_LENGTH);
        }
    
    
        public static byte[] decryptRaw(byte[] cipherBytes, byte[] keyBytes) throws Exception {
            byte[] IV = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherBytes, cipherBytes.length - MAX_IV_LENGTH, cipherBytes.length);
            byte[] RealBytes = Arrays.copyOf(cipherBytes, cipherBytes.length - MAX_IV_LENGTH);
            Cipher AesAlgorithm = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" );
            byte[] ValidKeyBytes = generateValidKey(keyBytes);
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(ValidKeyBytes, "AES");
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
            AesAlgorithm.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            byte[] Decrypted = AesAlgorithm.doFinal(RealBytes);
            return Decrypted;
        }
    
        public static byte[] encryptRaw(byte[] plainBytes, byte[] keyBytes) throws Exception {
            Cipher AesAlgorithm = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            byte[] ValidKeyBytes = generateValidKey(keyBytes);
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(ValidKeyBytes, "AES");
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(generateIV());
            AesAlgorithm.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            byte[] Encrypted = AesAlgorithm.doFinal(plainBytes);
            byte[] ret = new byte[Encrypted.length + MAX_IV_LENGTH];
            System.arraycopy(Encrypted, 0, ret, 0, Encrypted.length);
            System.arraycopy(ivParameterSpec.getIV(), 0, ret, Encrypted.length, MAX_IV_LENGTH);
            return ret;
        }
    
        private static byte[] generateIV() throws Exception {
            return generateRandomArray(MAX_IV_LENGTH);
        }
    
        public static byte[] generateRandomArray(int size) {
            SecureRandom RandomGenerator = new SecureRandom();
            byte[] ret = new byte[size];
            RandomGenerator.nextBytes(ret);
            return ret;
        }
    
        public static String encryptToBase64(String plaintext, String key) throws Exception {
            byte[] PlainBytes = plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] KeyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
            return Base64Manager.toBase64(encryptRaw(PlainBytes, KeyBytes), false);
        }
    
    }
```

```
    public class Program {
        public static  void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            String plainText = "plain text";
            String password = "password";
            String encrypted = AesManager.encryptToBase64(plainText, password);
            System.out.println(encrypted);
            System.out.println(AesManager.decryptFromBase64(encrypted, password));
        }
    }
```

---

**Output**

**Java**

```
PS C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Documentos\NetBeansProjects\TestAes\target> java -cp .\TestAes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.testaes.Program
leHBoUoB54bd9JEa9s9INohjVjmb2RZqVzrz2uYEstg=
plain text
PS C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Documentos\NetBeansProjects\TestAes\target> java -cp .\TestAes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.testaes.Program
wC6o7cUqZn9KS88L11OuNR2lGDcJ6zBrK1etJEpMHEg=
plain text
PS C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Documentos\NetBeansProjects\TestAes\target> java -cp .\TestAes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.testaes.Program
gfM1uVf2a3x6Q/N0XhpDI4svUZx4kTmcl0wkjJfNQrw=
plain text
PS C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Documentos\NetBeansProjects\TestAes\target>
```

[image: Java]

**Dotnet**

```
PS C:\Users\Megam\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleAppCs\bin\Debug\net5.0> .\ConsoleAppCs.exe
4GTqXhjkh0tXNI6Q4hShSdPPrKcWVEqA5LRBn6fBCH8=
plain text

PS C:\Users\Megam\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleAppCs\bin\Debug\net5.0> .\ConsoleAppCs.exe
aYY1sxre9KfLqkA1XtvN4IwGau6mYInmuvkopFXuKQA=
plain text

PS C:\Users\Megam\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleAppCs\bin\Debug\net5.0> .\ConsoleAppCs.exe
7lesPYAHQxdiCN4Cv5yWyWJlf5pqIukznZzpZTOOFeg=
plain text

PS C:\Users\Megam\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleAppCs\bin\Debug\net5.0>
```

[image: dotnet]