# C# AES Encryption Need

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I have an Encrypted string and function to decrypt it. Now I need to edit this string and encrypt it. When I use this function to encrypt and decrypt in result strings are not the same.

Orginal encrypted string:

```
APpuC6G3f3cUKaAuOFXOGIo9rwz/+fQ0tBCi6Fk40THVnIT+au7JXkOQHdgPcpQ3VUrXw69rIL+QRsHea5+Q6TxOeuAnzkU8c3UClx6Toe+jOIVi3DlkLIGzE8DmyBArtZYpKTOt4rrOSDyLKifdgcM+MgwuJbDXyXVuQyp2C42zZ1ETPUOF2TSIZKhnMSR43FFy8WEbpKBAjkPmgVpqqhrjabu+JHbj7kPIxGGjDHGaCCyCtFwsk3264Lv4GTp049SCjNNYV0NVcN4wV0MaWMEO0iLuNGkseHuu5Snvp3YzZfXxDBWSLOUXc2zeXL2tA6So9WA5P3lZ/ga5i366EQ==
```

Orginal encrypted string after decrypt:

```
{"status":"PASS","data":{"map_path":"VOtKu0.yGT","file_extension":"KAmXWV","username":"damianek","timestamp":9999999999},"message":"Logged in successfully. Your license will run out at 2021-12-03 18:41:39"}
```

Orginal decrypt function:

```
public static string Decypher(string var1)
    {
        var1 = var1.Trim();
        byte[] array = Convert.FromBase64String(var1);
        byte[] array2 = new byte[16];
        byte[] array3 = new byte[32];
        byte[] array4 = new byte[array.Length - 48];
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            array2[i] = array[i];
        }
        for (int j = 16; j < 48; j++)
        {
            array3[j - 16] = array[j];
        }
        for (int k = 48; k < array.Length; k++)
        {
            array4[k - 48] = array[k];
        }
        ivv = array2;
        Aes aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Key = GetToken();
        aes.IV = array2;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateDecryptor();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            
            cryptoStream.Write(array4, 0, array4.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] array5 = memoryStream.ToArray();
            result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(array5, 0, array5.Length);
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

My encrypt function:

```
public void EncryptStringToBytes()
    {
        string plainText = textBox2.Text;
        byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        byte[] encrypted;
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = GetToken();
            aesAlg.IV = new byte[16];
            aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }
```

String after my encrypt & decrypt with orginal function:

```
?%j>]???r?????":"KAmXWV","username":"damianek","timestamp":1637955589},"message":"Logged in successfully. Your license will run out at 2021-12-03 18:41:39"}
```

**EDIT:**
Now encrypt function look:

```
public void EncryptStringToBytes()
    {
        string plainText = textBox2.Text.Trim();
        byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);
        byte[] encrypted;
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = GetToken();
            aesAlg.IV = GetIV();
            aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.Key, 0, aesAlg.Key.Length);
                msEncrypt.Flush();
                using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    csEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.Key, 0, aesAlg.Key.Length);
                    using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }
```

But string after encrypt & decrypt look:

```
;???En  Dp??g???{"status":"PASS","data":{"map_path":"VOtKu0.yGT","file_extension":"KAmXWV","username":"damianek","timestamp":1637955589},"message":"Logged in successfully. Your license will run out at 2021-12-03 18:41:39"}
```

Comment: You need to prepend the `IV`, so should have `msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV);` before the main write. Also you are missing `using` blocks to dispose various objects, and the decrypt is using `ASCII` but the encrypt is using `UTF8`

Comment: Ok added `msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);` and change UTF8 to ASCII and now after decrypt look little better `H?6??/u?,)??_?;?,"file_extension":"KAmXWV","username":"damianek","timestamp":1637955589},"message":"Logged in successfully. Your license will run out at 2021-12-03 18:41:39"}`

Comment: Easiest AES implementation in C#   https://github.com/c4bo3l/crypto.aes

Comment: `Decypher()` expects (Base64 encoded) data of the form `a|b|c`, where `a` is the 16 bytes IV, `b` is some 32 bytes data (possibly a MAC) and `c` is the actual ciphertext. Note that `b` is separated in `Decypher()` though, but not used. Your encryption (in the EDIT part) in `EncryptStringToBytes()` currently concatenates key and ciphertext, so that doesn't fit. The purpose of `csEncrypt.Write(...)` is not clear to me.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks this help me, and i found solution ;)

Comment: @Charlieface, no you don't, prepending IV to data being transferedout of system is defeating its purpose. Unless you have any means to transfer IV to client different channels or encrypt and decrypt is happening in same system, it is better to start with zero IV

Answer (score 1):

My C# AES implementation

from my answer [AES Crypto C# compatible Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67629113/3158594)

- The IV is randomized in every Encrypt process to get different output with same text and avoid to intruders/attackers get original text easily.
- The default mode is CBC.
- The encoding used is UTF-8. UTF-8 is the most widely used encoding on the web.

You can test/run this code on https://replit.com/@JomaCorpFX/AesCbcEncrypt#main.cs

**References**

• [Block cipher mode of operation - IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Initialization_vector_.28IV.29)
• [When using AES and CBC, is it necessary to keep the IV secret?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17044/when-using-aes-and-cbc-is-it-necessary-to-keep-the-iv-secret)
• [Initialization Vector - IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)
• [Generate keys for encryption and decryption - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/generating-keys-for-encryption-and-decryption)

> Creating and managing keys is an important part of the cryptographic process. Symmetric algorithms require the creation of a key and an initialization vector (IV). You must keep this key secret from anyone who shouldn't decrypt your data. The IV doesn't have to be secret but should be changed for each session

**The code**

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public enum HashAlgorithm
{
    MD5,
    SHA1,
    SHA256,
    SHA384,
    SHA512
}

public class HashManager
{
    public static byte[] ToRawHash(byte[] data, HashAlgorithm algorithm)
    {
        byte[] hash;
        switch (algorithm)
        {
            case HashAlgorithm.MD5:
                MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
                hash = md5.ComputeHash(data, 0, data.Length);
                return hash;
            case HashAlgorithm.SHA1:
                SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
                hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);
                return hash;
            case HashAlgorithm.SHA256:
                SHA256Managed sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
                hash = sha256.ComputeHash(data);
                return hash;
            case HashAlgorithm.SHA384:
                SHA384Managed sha384 = new SHA384Managed();
                hash = sha384.ComputeHash(data);
                return hash;
            case HashAlgorithm.SHA512:
                SHA512Managed sha512 = new SHA512Managed();
                hash = sha512.ComputeHash(data, 0, data.Length);
                return hash;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Algorithm");
        }
    }
}

public class AesManager
{
    private const int MAX_IV_LENGTH = 16;
    private const int MAX_KEY_LENGTH = 32;

    private static byte[] GenerateValidKey(byte[] keyBytes)
    {
        byte[] ret = new byte[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
        byte[] hash = HashManager.ToRawHash(keyBytes, HashAlgorithm.SHA256);
        Array.Copy(hash, ret, MAX_KEY_LENGTH);
        return ret;
    }


    public static byte[] EncryptRaw(byte[] PlainBytes, byte[] Key)
    {
        AesManaged AesAlgorithm = new AesManaged()
        {
            Key = GenerateValidKey(Key)
        };
        AesAlgorithm.GenerateIV();
        var Encrypted = AesAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(PlainBytes, 0, PlainBytes.Length);
        byte[] ret = new byte[Encrypted.Length + MAX_IV_LENGTH];
        Array.Copy(Encrypted, ret, Encrypted.Length);
        Array.Copy(AesAlgorithm.IV, 0, ret, ret.Length - MAX_IV_LENGTH, MAX_IV_LENGTH);
        return ret;
    }

    public static byte[] DecryptRaw(byte[] CipherBytes, byte[] Key)
    {
        AesManaged AesAlgorithm = new AesManaged()
        {
            Key = GenerateValidKey(Key)
        };
        byte[] IV = new byte[MAX_IV_LENGTH];
        Array.Copy(CipherBytes, CipherBytes.Length - MAX_IV_LENGTH, IV, 0, MAX_IV_LENGTH);
        AesAlgorithm.IV = IV;
        byte[] RealBytes = new byte[CipherBytes.Length - MAX_IV_LENGTH];
        Array.Copy(CipherBytes, RealBytes, CipherBytes.Length - MAX_IV_LENGTH);
        return AesAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(RealBytes, 0, RealBytes.Length); ;
    }


    public static String EncryptToBase64(String Plaintext, String Key)
    {
        byte[] PlainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Plaintext);
        return Base64Manager.ToBase64(EncryptRaw(PlainBytes, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key)), false);
    }



    public static String DecryptFromBase64(String CipherText, String Key)
    {
        byte[] CiPherBytes = Base64Manager.Base64ToByteArray(CipherText);
        byte[] Encrypted = DecryptRaw(CiPherBytes, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key));
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encrypted, 0, Encrypted.Length);
    }

}

public class Base64Manager
{
    public static byte[] Base64ToByteArray(String base64)
    {
        return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    }

    public static String ToBase64(byte[] data, Boolean insertLineBreaks = default(Boolean))
    {
        return insertLineBreaks ? Convert.ToBase64String(data, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks) : Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    }
}



public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Plain text: ");
        string plainText = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Password: ");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();
        string encrypted = AesManager.EncryptToBase64(plainText, password);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine($"Password: {password}" );
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted: {encrypted}");
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Decrypted: {AesManager.DecryptFromBase64(encrypted, password)}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output**
[image: output]

Comment: By adding your IV to encrypted data, you are actually defeating its purpose by revealing it, so it is just better to use a zero array instead! IV with random value is usable when both encrypting and decrypting side are same application or at least they are able to transfer it from a diffrenet means than prepending to encrypted data. Also I'm not sure why you are hashing your key that is already a random bytes. it doesn't make it any more secure.

Comment: The IV is used to add randomness to the result, the same plaintext being encrypted several times with the same key its result is never the same. If the IV is secret, it would always be necessary to carry it to decipher. That is not the goal. The goal is to use only the key that is secret, the iv just adds noise or confusion to the result. If you use the same IV every time you get the same encrypted result.  Check the references on this answer.

Comment: Aes with 256bits key. Key size is mandatory, for 256bits is 32 bytes(256/8). GenerateValidKey take any input, computes the hash and take 32bytes from SHA-256 result. The exact size of the key required for AES-256. If you use the incorrect key size(byte[]) an exception will be thrown. For example if your key is "@12345678" this value have in UTF-8, 9 bytes but 32 bytes are required, for this reason the Key is used to compute the SHA-256 hash, the resulting hash is 32 bytes length.

Comment: AES encryption usually starts with a handshake, which IV is zero and then continues with previous IV for next encryption. if for any reason, two side of cypher go out of sync they start another handshake. This is at least how it is done in finance industry. if randomness was the reason you could add a 2 byte number in front of your text before encrypt and remove that two bytes on the other side after decrypt, it creates enough randomness. I believe having IV not attached to encrypted data makes decrypting it with brute force twice harder.

Comment: In real life  applications, key is always stored as a key not a phrase that then you simply hash it to get a more secure key. if a user uses 1234 as their secret, it is just a 4 byte key and same much weak, a 256bit key (32 byte) is of course more secure. in Finance industry keys are created in applications and split to 2 parts, each part is given to one person for recovery purpose and the rest of keys used in that organization are derived from that key usually inside an HSM or TPM. a 1234 secret can be easily revealed and remembered, and shouldn't be used at all.

Comment: The hash process in my implementation is to create a valid key for AES-256 encrypt method in C# or Java.  There are many strategies to provide correct key for methods in C# or Java to avoid exceptions. 1. if keyLength<32 then pad with zeroes to complete 32 bytes required. 2. My case, calculates SHA-256 of any key, the SHA-256 result is exactly 32 bytes. 3. Your desired strategy to provide correct key size for C# or Java libs. 4. Another strategy. 5. Another strategy...... Nth: Another strat.

Comment: In real life applications, non-technical users use simple passwords, based on ASCII characters. At the enterprise level, keys can be more complex, long ascii strings or random bytes. In my implementation you can use byte[] keys or string keys. Refers to IV, the IV doesn't have to be secret but should be changed for each session.